# Развернуть матрицу, используя скалярные выражения

Tags: c#, матрицы

Добрый день.

Есть задание:

Дана квадратная матрица размерности N, например:

---

### | 5 |12|88|

### |65|54|43|

### |81|92|56|

Нужно ее развернуть на 90 градусов, чтобы вышло:

---

### |81|65| 5 |

### |92|54|12|

### |56|43|88|

Вопрос: как это сделать, не копируя матрицу в память и без использования любых динамических структур?
Можно использовать счетное количество скалярных переменных, не зависящее от размерности матрицы.

UPD:

Делаю так:

```
public static void Rotate()
{
    int tmp;
    for (int i = 0; i < n/2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i; j < n - 1 - i; j++)
        {
            tmp = matrix[i,j];
            matrix[i,j] = matrix[n - j - 1,i];
            matrix[n - j - 1,i] = matrix[n - i - 1,n - j - 1];
            matrix[n - i - 1,n - j - 1] = matrix[j,n - i - 1];
            matrix[j, n - i - 1] = tmp;
        }
     }
}
```

Спасибо!

Comment: @Telsystems, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Размерность у матрицы 2, `N` — это размер.

По сути — вам нужна одна доп. переменная. Пройдитесь по верхнему левому квадрату, скопируйте значение по кругу в остальные квадраты (81 на место 5, 56 на место 81, 88 на место 56, 5 на место 88: для этого вам придётся запомнить 5 в доп. переменной). Не ошибитесь с центральным столбцом и строкой, если такие есть.

Дерзайте, всё на самом деле просто.

Comment: @Telsystems: вроде правильно. Проверьте на чётном и нечётном размере.

Comment: к сожалению такая реализация не работает с матрицей с нечетным размером. не подскажите как можна это исправить?

Comment: @Telsystems: Попробуйте заменить в цикле условие `i < n/2` на `2 * i < n`. Для случая матрицы 3x3 первое условие исключает `i = 1`, а второе включает.

Comment: не получается потому, что оно при копировании пытается скопировать значение в [0,4], а масив создан как [4,3]. Правильно ли у меня реализован разворот и если да, то как можна решить эту проблемму без использования дополнительной матрицы и использования динамических структур?

Comment: @Telsystems: Подождите, а как вы собираетесь разворачивать неквадратную матрицу? Матрица обязана быть квадратной.

Comment: @Telsystems: Так нечего же гуглить! Неквадратную матрицу в принципе нельзя развернуть, т. к. к-во строк и столбцов меняются местами. Поэтому ограничьтесь квадратным случаем.

Comment: @Telsystems: пожалуйста! Тогда задача, по идее, решена?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача решена.

```
int tmp, i, j; // 3 дополнительных переменных
for (i = 0; 2*i < n; i++)
{
    for (j = i; j < n - 1 - i; j++)
    {
        tmp = matrix[i,j];
        matrix[i,j] = matrix[n - j - 1,i];
        matrix[n - j - 1,i] = matrix[n - i - 1,n - j - 1];
        matrix[n - i - 1,n - j - 1] = matrix[j,n - i - 1];
        matrix[j, n - i - 1] = tmp;
    }
 }
```

Comment: @Telsystems: внёс решение.